# Make pure native Exe for C#/VB.net Application [No need .net framework to run Exe]

Tags: c#

How to make pure native Exe for C#/VB.net Application? [After that No need .net framework to run that Exe]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Deploying C# (.NET 2.0) application as a portable application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248289/deploying-c-net-2-0-application-as-a-portable-application)

Comment: Kind of tired of such questions :) If you don't like the framework, don't use C# or VB.NET. That saves you a lot of time. Personally speaking, you can consider Delphi or C++Builder.

Answer (score 5):

Short answer: you can't.

Longer answer: there are programs which wrap the framework up, such as [VMware ThinApp](http://www.vmware.com/products/thinapp/) (previously known as Thinstall) - but they're still *effectively* using the framework, just in a different deployment form.

Even longer answer: Mono has an [ahead-of-time compiler and bundler](http://www.mono-project.com/Mono:Runtime#Ahead-of-time_compilation) which allows it to create native apps (e.g. for the iPhone) - but I don't know what the state of play is with using that for Windows, and the normal caveats of compatibility between .NET and Mono apply.

Anything like this is likely to have significant implications if your application uses reflection, loads plug-ins etc. Personally I'd advise against it unless you've got a *really* good reason for not just installing the normal framework.