# How to convert vb.NET application to portable EXE?

Tags: vb.net

I made the simplest vb.NET application (NOT console) and I want to convert it into a portable EXE file.

I found a program that converts regular programs to portable ones, but I don't know where vb.NET applications are installed.

Comment: The time you build the source code of your program it becomes a portable application. Try navigating to your project folder and search for the bin/debug location, inside it is your portable .exe file.

Comment: [ThinApp](https://www.vmware.com/products/thinapp.html) is still around. No idea on pricing. See [here](https://www.petenetlive.com/KB/Article/0000612) for a tutorial, and this old [PAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248289/deploying-c-sharp-net-2-0-application-as-a-portable-application) for more info.